# java executing file while building

Tags: java, svn

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z1uS.png)I got a project and I will modify it, but while compiling it tries to execute svn (Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive status").
I tried a simple locate in the project and couldn´t find where this command is started (located "svn" and nothing).
I dont intend to install tortoise or any other version control.
How do I find where this command is being executed to remove it?
The search on netbeans didn´t show anything relevant for "cmd", "svn" or "exec"

Answer (score 0):

External processes are executed via the Runtime and the Process classes.  You obtain the runtime class using

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("<<command line>>");
```

If you're looking via an IDE, I would look for any usages of the Runtime class.  If you're doing a text search, I'd look for the text `.getRuntime()` and/or `exec(`.

Answer (score 0):

in the pom.xml I changed to false the maven plugin:
 `<doCheck>false</doCheck>
<doUpdate>false</doUpdate>`